# Why navigation to another page is cancelled and user is redirected to the same page they are on?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a customer that has a weird issue going on on her computer when she tries to navigate through my web application (her Chrome version is `100.x`):
There is a page in the application which displays a list of orders and links with each one to post back to the same page where serverside causes a redirection to take the user to the order details page. The hyperlink runs a javascript function like the following when clicked.

```js
    function NavigateToOrder(orderId) {
     // Some input fields changed here
     document.forms[0].submit(); // there is only one form in the entire dom.
    }
```

It works fine everywhere but on her computer when she clicks an order, she does see the page refreshing but she ends on the same order list page.

I have made her go to the Chrome dev tools and here is what I noticed or what we've tried.

The network tab does show a `POST` request of the `.submit()` call, but it shows as canceled in red color right away, and it executes another POST to the existing URL afterward so she ends up staying on the order list page.

I thought there was some `onsubmit()` logic doing it so I made her go to the `Elements` tab, and click on the `Form` element, and in the `Event Listeners` I made her Remove the only listener that was present. She clicks the link again, and the same thing happens.

I do have New Relic Browser instrumentation script for observability, I made her search those `<script>` tags in the `Elements` list and made her remove those, still, the `POST` gets canceled.

I have done all of this in a `Chrome Incognito` window with all the extensions disabled, leaving only Google Docs Offline extension enabled.

Are there any other ideas of what I should check? She is very sweet in giving me so much time going through this painful debugging process. And I should mention that for some reason she is not able to allow me control of her shared screen so I am dictating this to her.

EDIT 1: Chrome `Network` tab shows all those POST requests with `Initiator` as "Other" instead of the actual places in the `Sources`.

Comment: My first guess was going to be an ad blocker, but you said that disabling extensions didn't fix it. It sounds like a firewall of some kind.

Comment: @Barmar Can a firewall intercept a form's submission on the browser and redirect the user to another POST?

Comment: Another thing is anything in the form named submit 
Let them also try in incognito mode

Comment: @mplungjan They did try incognito. And DevTools shows that it starts the post but it then gets cancelled for some reason.

Comment: @fahadash A firewall can intercept the post and return a TCP RST that would cause it to be cancelled.

Comment: Does the JS do `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Please show the markup for the form.

Comment: @spender Unfortunately the markup carries some sensitive information that I'd have to obfuscate first, and the next session would be next week so.

Comment: @Bamar The only handler of `onsubmit` was removed during the troubleshooting session.

Comment: Do they load some form handler or prettifyer?
Can they copy the form without ANY other stuff, just the form?
What does the network tab say in the cancelled request? Did you tick the "preserve log" across page loads

Comment: @mplungjan Preserve log is checked. Network tab shows the cancelled POST in red, nothing much; the cancelled request is followed by another POST which is to the same page that user is already on.

Comment: What is the error from the submit call? Red indicates that it failes, but when you click on it you can see more info. CORS? AddBlocker? Firewall? Whats the return / response code?

Comment: You describe the behavior on the problematic client: a failed POST /order followed by a POST /orderlist. What's the behavior on a client where it works? POST /order followed by GET /order/45? Or just the POST /order?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen On the /OrderList page user clicks an order which generates a POST on /OrderDetail/nnnn that is immediately shown as `Cancelled` and is followed by a /OrderList.

Behavior on the client where it works: After a click to an order link, a POST /OrderDetail/nnnn isn't `Cancelled` and user is navigated to the new screen.

Comment: @0stone0 It does not show as failed, it shows as `Cancelled` as if during the redirect process another Javascript code somewhere ran and redirected user to another URL instead. When I click on the `Cancelled` call all I am able to see is Request Headers, there is no response stuff since the request was cancelled.

Comment: Are these all POST requests, or also GET requests?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen All POST.

Answer (score 1):

You have another way to inspect events on an element on chrome devtools:

In your html ui, right clic on the element you want to monitor, then choos "inspect" from contextual menu:

[image]

Doing this you will open the Element tab of devtools.

Then clic now on console tab and type this at console prompt:

```
monitorEvents($0)
```

and the hit return.

From this point console will monitor all events on the element previously selected:

[image]

You can stop monitor element by typing this at console prompt:

```
unmonitorEvents($0)
```

Answer (score 0):

From chrome 103, you can capture click events in the recorder panel of devtools:

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-103/

For example a double clic on a SO button:

[image]

Once saved, you can replay the captured action and analyze what hapenned and also view source code for each action:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This sounds good. Could you improve the answer and add instructions on how to get to this option in chrome dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

Give you a third solution!

In devtools, go to "source" tab. Click and expand on "Event Listener Breakpoints" on right side. Then expand mouse and check "Double click".

From this point each time a double click is done in the page, debugger will suspend like when you put a beakpoint. So you know when a double click is done.

[image]